# Ajax.actionlink() not working with POST method (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

sorry for my bad english, but let's to the problem.

i am trying to do a POST into the action **complete** of the controller **occurrence**,
but the action don't receive the POST and the javascript console returns this error
**500 Internal Server Error**

This is my **Ajax.actionlink()**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Complete", "Complete", "Occurrence", new { id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

And this is my action **Complete** into the controller **Occurrence**

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Complete(int id)
 {
     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
 }
```

Someone has passed for the same situation?
Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your action is decorated with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` meaning that it will expect that the anti forgery token gets sent into the POST request payload. This isn't the case. In your request you are only sending some id (`new { id = Model.Id }`).

Once possible workaround is to use an Ajax.BeginForm instead which will contain the anti forgery token:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Complete", "Occurrence", new { id = Model.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <button type="submit">Complete</button>
}
```

The `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` will generate a hidden field containing the required anti forgery token that will be sent along with the AJAX request to the server.

Comment: thank you very much, now i know what is the problem, was almost crazy with this.